# Can a truth table show that a false statement is true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Take this statement:

- If a quadrilateral is a rectangle, then it has two pairs of parallel sides.

Its inverse is this:

- If a quadrilateral is not a rectangle, then it does not have two pairs of parallel sides.

The truth table says that if $p$ and $q$ are both false, then "$p$ implies $q$" is true. Thus, as $p$ and $q$ in the inverse statement are both false, the inverse statement ought to be TRUE.

Doesn't this contradict the fact that the inverse statement is evidently FALSE though?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you know that $p \rightarrow q$ is true when $p$ and $q$ are false. The inverse $\neg p \rightarrow \neg q$ is also true when $p$ and $q$ are both false.

Your confusion seems to be that you are conflating the above situation with a different claim: $(p\rightarrow q) \rightarrow (q\rightarrow p)$. Notice that this is false in general, but **given** that $p$ and $q$ are both false, it is true.

So in your example it is indeed true that if a quadrilateral is a rectangle there are parallel sides, and indeed the converse of this statement is false, so we don't have $(p\rightarrow q) \rightarrow (q\rightarrow p)$ where $p$ is "is a rectangle" and $q$ is "has parallel sides". However, if I am given a quadrilateral which is neither a rectangle, nor has parallel sides, both the conditionals are true, so in this situation they imply one another (as a true thing is implied by everything).

Answer (score 1):

$P\rightarrow Q$ is equivalent to saying that,

> - If $P$ is true then $Q$ is true.
> - If $Q$ is false then $P$ is false.

In other words, $P\rightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $\neg Q\rightarrow \neg P$.

In your example we take $$P:=\text{a quadrilateral is a rectangle}\\Q:=\text{a quadrilateral has two pairs of parallel sides}$$

It is not clear what you mean by **inverse**. However, if you want to mean **converse** then there is a mistake in your converse. It should be,

> If a quadrilateral has doesn't have two pairs of parallel sides then it is not a rectangle.

And this is consistent with the truth table.

Answer (score 1):

> Its inverse is this:
>
> - If a quadrilateral **is not a rectangle**, then it **does not have two pairs of parallel sides**.
>
> as $p$ and $q$ in the inverse statement are both false,

Your reasoning error is right in the last line above. In itself, the sentence $$\text{if not }p, \text{then not }q$$ does not convey that $p$ and $q$ are false; in particular, the sentence "not $p$" just means the negation of the sentence "$p$"; it does not mean, "$p$ is false"; $p$ could be any sentence, which could be either true or false.

> the inverse statement is evidently FALSE

Yes. To prove that the inverse statement is false, we just need to exhibit a quadrilateral that is not a rectangle yet ***does*** have two pairs of parallel sides; so, just exhibit a rhombus.

Notice that our proof does not call for a truth table. This is because truth tables handle only propositional-logic statements, the the inverse statement is not actually in propositional logic. This is because it tacitly means ‘for every quadrilateral $x,$ if $x$ **is not a rectangle**, then $x$ **does not have two pairs of parallel sides**’ and has an implicit universal quantification (the ‘for every quadrilateral $x$’).

So, ultimately, there has been no contradiction after all, and a truth table indeed never shows that a false statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

I think all of the answers miss the point that the statements under discussion are meant to be general statements.  The most natural interpretation of "If a quadrilateral is a rectangle, then it has two pairs of parallel sides" is "If any quadrilateral is a rectangle, then it has two pairs of parallel sides."  (If it were a statement about a particular quadrilateral, it would have been something like "If this quadrilateral is a rectangle, then it has two pairs of parallel sides.")  So the correct interpretations of the statements must include universal quantifiers.

Let's let the universe of discourse be the set of all quadrilaterals.  For any $x$ in that universe (that is, any quadrilateral), let $p(x)$ mean "$x$ is a rectangle" and let $q(x)$ mean "$x$ has two pairs of parallel sides."  Then the logical representations of the two statements are:

- For every $x$, if $p(x)$ then $q(x)$; that is, $\forall x(p(x) \to q(x))$
- For every $x$, if $\neg p(x)$ then $\neg q(x)$; that is, $\forall x(\neg p(x) \to \neg q(x))$

Now, the OP says that the second statement is clearly false, and that's right.  Why?  Because there are *some* values of $x$ for which the conditional statement $\neg p(x) \to \neg q(x)$ comes out false.  For example, if $x$ is a parallelogram that is not a rectangle, then $\neg p(x)$ is true and $\neg q(x)$ is false, so the conditional is false.

It seems that the OP is bothered by the fact that there are *some* values of $x$ for which $\neg p(x)$ and $\neg q(x)$ are both false, and therefore the conditional statement $\neg p(x) \to \neg q(x)$ is true.  Yes, there are some such values of $x$, but there are other values of $x$ for which the conditional is false, so it is not the case that *for all $x$*, $\neg p(x) \to \neg q(x)$ comes out true.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused because probably the concept of truth tables was not explained clearly enough to you.

> According to a truth table, if "p is false, and q is false" then "p implies q" is true.

This is correct, but it is not the only thing that "p implies q" means. There are four conditions listed in the **whole** truth table that have to be satisfied by "p implies q".

The truth table also says:

> If "p" is true and "q" is false, then "p implies q" is false.
>
> If "p" is false and "q" is true, then "p implies q" is true.

These mean that "q implies p" is not **always** the same as "p implies q", because when "p" is true and "q" is false, they are different. However, they are the same when "p" and "q" are both true or both false.

When two (compound) propositions are always the same regardless of the truth values of the atomic propositions, we say that they are **equivalent**. So "p implies q" and "q implies p" are not equivalent if "p" and "q" are atoms.

On the other hand, it is **possible** for "p implies q" and "q implies p" to be equivalent if "p" and "q" are not atoms, even if "p" and "q" are different. For example, "(a and b) implies (b and a)" and "(b and a) implies (a and b)" are equivalent.